# How to know the physical size of the database in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, code-first

Is it possible to know code first created database physical `*.mdf` file size in bytes, using only methods or properties of Entity Framework classes? And if it's possible, then how to do that???

Comment: I googled only some tricky SQL queries to do that by calculating and summarizing of all entries size, but I suggest there is some easier, safer and quicker way.

Comment: There isn't. EF is a database independent ORM. What if the database is split into multiple files? Your use case is a frequently occuring scenario.

Answer (score 10):

You can get the database size by exec the `sp_spaceused`

```
var ef = new EFContext();
var sqlConn = ef.Database.Connection as SqlConnection;
var cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_spaceused")
{
    CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure,
    Connection = sqlConn as SqlConnection
};
var adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
var dataset = new DataSet();
sqlConn.Open();
adp.Fill(dataset);
sqlConn.Close();
//You will get:
//database_name database_size   unallocated space
//performance       1091.00 MB      456.00 MB
//
//reserved  data        index_size  unused
//557056 KB 540680 KB   10472 KB    5904 KB
Console.WriteLine(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][1]);
```