# Executing stored procedures and getting the output

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to read the size of my database, and I can do this in SQL Server - but how do I run the following code in Entity Framework and get the output?

```
USE Impro_V2
GO
sp_spaceused
GO
```

or

```
EXEC sp_helpdb N'Impro_V2';
```

Using `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` I get a result of "-1". I am not even sure whether that is failed.

How do run code like that?

Comment: You can use the `context.Database.GetDbConnection` extension method to get the underlying `DbConnection` object, and then use it to execute raw ADO.NET commands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first)

Comment: For some reason I dont see the GetDbConnection. The other does not give much, just a "-1"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here:
[How to know the physical size of the database in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031393/how-to-know-the-physical-size-of-the-database-in-entity-framework/12031633)

The code is simple:

```
var ef = new MyDbContext();
var sqlConn = ef.Database.Connection as SqlConnection;

var cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_spaceused")
{
    CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure,
    Connection = sqlConn as SqlConnection
};
var adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
var dataset = new DataSet();
sqlConn.Open();
adp.Fill(dataset);
sqlConn.Close();
// example read
foreach (DataTable table in dataset.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            console.write(row[icol].tostring());
etc
```